# TypeError: 'Zipcode' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror, zipcode

I'm using Python3 and have a pandas df that looks like

```
    zip
0   07105
1   00000
2   07030
3   07032
4   07032
```

I would like to add state and city using the python package `uszipcode`

```
import uszipcode
search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=False)
def zco(x):
    print(search.by_zipcode(x)['City'])

df['City'] = df[['zip']].fillna(0).astype(int).apply(zco)
```

However, I get the following error

```
TypeError: 'Zipcode' object is not subscriptable
```

Can someone help with the error? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call `search.by_zipcode(x)` returns a [`ZipCode()` instance](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/uszipcode/model.html#uszipcode.model.Zipcode), not a dictionary, so applying `['City']` to that object fails.

Instead, use either the `.major_city` attribute of the shorter alias, the [`.city` attribute](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/uszipcode/model.html#uszipcode.model.BaseZipcode.city); you want to *return* that value, not print it:

```
def zco(x):
    return search.by_zipcode(x).city
```

If all you are going to use the `uszipcode` project for is mapping zip codes to state and city names, you don’t need to use the full database (a 450MB download).  Just stick with the ‘simple’ version, which is only 9MB, by leaving out the `simple_zipcode=False` argument to `SearchEngine()`.

Next, this is going to be *really really slow*. `.apply()` uses a simple loop under the hood, and for each row the `.by_zipcode()` method will query a SQLite database using SQLAlchemy, create a single result object with all the columns from the matching row, then return that object, just so you can get a single attribute from them.

You'd be much better off querying the database directly, with the Pandas [SQL methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-sql). The `uszipcode` package is still useful here as it handles downloading the database for you and creating a SQLAlchemy session, the [`SearchEngine.ses` attribute](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/uszipcode/search.html#uszipcode.search.SearchEngine) gives you direct access to it, but from there I'd just do:

```
from uszipcode import SearchEngine, SimpleZipcode

search = SearchEngine()
query = (
    search.ses.query(
        SimpleZipcode.zipcode.label('zip'),
        SimpleZipcode.major_city.label('city'),
        SimpleZipcode.state.label('state'),
    ).filter(
        SimpleZipcode.zipcode.in_(df['zip'].dropna().unique())
    )
).selectable
zipcode_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, search.ses.connection(), index_col='zip')
```

to create a Pandas Dataframe with all your unique zipcodes mapped to city and state columns. You can then [join your dataframe with the zipcode dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#merging-join):

```
df = pd.merge(df, zipcode_df, how='left', left_on='zip', right_index=True)
```

This adds `city` and `state` columns to your original dataframe. If you need to pull in more columns, add them to the `search.ses.query(...)` portion, using `.label()` to give them a suitable column name in the output dataframe (without a `.label()`, they'll get prefixed with `simple_zipcode_` or `zipcode_`, depending on the class you are using). Pick from the [model attributes documented](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/uszipcode/model.html#module-uszipcode.model), but take into account that if you need access to the [full `Zipcode` model attributes](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/uszipcode/model.html#uszipcode.model.Zipcode) you need to use `SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=False)` to ensure you get the full 450MB dataset at your disposal, then use `Zipcode.<column>.label(...)` instead of `SimpleZipcode.<column>.label(...)` in the query.

With the zipcodes as the index in the `zipcode_df` dataframe, that's going to be a lot faster (*zippier* :-)) than using SQLAlchemy on each row individually.

Comment: Thank you, I meant to use return, was testing with a print. Your code works, but this package is super slow. Can you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: @qqplot: added an alernative; having Pandas do the merging.