# Creating State Abbreviations from a Zip Code column that contains NaNs in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with ZIP codes or NaNs in a column. I would like to create a state_abbreviation column in order to make cloropleth maps.

_id     zip
0       NaN
1     12345

dtype: object

```
from uszipcode import SearchEngine, SimpleZipcode, Zipcode
import pandas as pd

zipcode = "the sample series above"
def extract_state (zipcode_column):
  """
  given a zipcode column, return a state abbr column  
  """
  search = SearchEngine()
  state = zipcode_column
  state[state.notna()]=state[state.notna()].apply(lambda x: search.by_zipcode(x).state_abbr)
  return state

extract_state(zipcode)
```

I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

I believe the NaNs are unable to be processed by the zipcode searcher, but I thought I was not selecting them with the apply function when I use

```
state.notna()
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is `print (type(zipcode))` ?

Comment: `print(type(zipcode))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. I have tried changing to `
`print(type(zipcode))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`, and receive the same error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my approach was fundamentally flawed. A faster way to create a state column(and city!) that reduces the number of sql queries is featured here: [TypeError: 'Zipcode' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011880/typeerror-zipcode-object-is-not-subscriptable). Thank you all, for your questions and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the column.

You might want to try this.

```
state[state['zip'].notnull()]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I receive the same error when applying. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'`